# Can't edit Microsoft Word template

Tags: microsoft-word, templates, microsoft-word-2003

I am trying to change an existing Microsoft Word template.  It's the 28 line legal pleading template found here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/pleading-form-with-28-lines-TC006087001.aspx

After much effort searching menus, I was able to change the "Summary of Pleading" text at the bottom of the page by selecting View -> Header and Footer.  (I changed it to just be the page number.)

How do I change the vertical lines on the left and right of the page, and the line numbers - 1 to 28?  All that stuff needs to be a darker font.

The Microsoft help pages are of no help.  They say to modify a template, open the template file (.dot), make the changes, and save it.  That's funny. (NOT.)  I have the .dot file open, and I can't select those line numbers (1 to 28) to edit them.

Thanks.

(Microsoft Word 2003)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

these numbers and lines are in header/footer. double click on the top or bottom of page and do your modifications. other way is going to View > Header and footer.

remember that when you save that file, change format to DOT if you want to create a template (or after saving as DOC, rename it to DOT).

Comment: Thanks.  You are right.  I never would have imagined Microsoft would consider what's to the left / right of the page would be a "header."

Comment: haha. they would rename it to a more suggestive name, as "hidden elements".

Answer (score 0):

I had a issue with DOT file as well.  I use another program that uses the DOT file and pushes out picture to the file.  My program only uses DOT files, Word 2010 creates .docx files.  I've had to convert the DOT file, save it and then rename the new coverted file to the DOT file name.  That works for my program. To convert it, open the DOT file, select the file tab, and then info.  You'll find the convert function there.

Comment: well, the problem there is not with file extensions, but with some elements in a doc file that are not accessible to edit; so I showed that these lements are in header or footer and them can be accessible double clicking with mouse in he top of page or by view > header/footer menu. but it is nice to know how to do that conversion in Word 2010 :)